# How to clear cookies when error deserialize a user using passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

When I use `passport.deserializeUser` handler:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

If `done` was called with an `err`, do I got a chance to clear the cookies and redirect users to `/login` page? Does that functionality depends on the strategy I'm using? E.g. using `failureRedirect` option of local strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [continuation local storage](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage) and register it before passport.

```
var createNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace;
var writer = createNamespace('express');

app.use((req,res,next) => {
    namespace.bindEmitter(req);
    namespace.bindEmitter(res);
    namespace.run(() => {
        writer.set('req', req)
        writer.set('res', res);
        next()
    });
});

app.use(passport.initialize(), passport.session());
```

Then in your deserialize you can access the same namespace and pull the value out:

```
var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace;
var reader = getNamespace('express');

function deserialize(key, done) {
   try {
      ...
   } catch(e) {
      reader.get("req").logout()
   }
}
```

Comment: The module itself looks like a total hack! But that looks really good!

Comment: It is somewhat of a hack, especially given how Node handles I/O in various locations (events vs callbacks, etc.).  Angular2 is actually built on a similar technology called [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/).  It's meant to be a monkey patch to minimize the amount of custom code the average developer has to call.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `req.session.destroy` method.... So in your case:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
    req.session.destroy();
  });
});
```

And that techinacly may not "Fully" Log out the person in your app, so if you want an alternative you can use the clearCookie method provided:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
      req.session.destroy(function() {
      res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can I get the req variable?

Comment: yes, I'm using express. But this deserializeUser callback is not defined inside express route handler.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to do user initiated logout. I'm trying to handle error here by clearing cookies so user can re-login.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the right answer. At least not before editing. req object is not available here, because the api of passport.js doesn't provide it. This is not happening inside a express route handler.

Comment: Is that a logout button @Daiwei ?

Comment: If you look at http://passportjs.org/docs/configure , `deserializeUser` is directly defined on `passport` object, which has no access of `req` object. And this is not about logout. This is simply a user with invalid cookies requesting a server endpoint. It can be anything, e.g. API, JSON, or HTML. I need to handle potential errors when `deserializeUser`, that's it.

Comment: I know it is a req object. And thats not it, i use it Every day.

Answer (score 0):

Like @amanuel2 noted, you can use req to destroy the session.  Passport will pass `req` to `deserializeUser` if you ask for it:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(req, id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            req.session.destroy(function() {
               return done(err)
            }
        }
        done(null, user);
    });
});
```

So you can destroy the session, redirect, etc if there is a problem deserializing the session.